# Upper case BLOB vs lower case blob

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

This is a very strange problem .For my android application, I was creating a database table for storing images and when i have set "blob" as a data type for image column.
It was giving an error and as soon as i changed "blob" to "BLOB" it was running perfect .As far as i know Uppercase  and lowercase didn't matter in MySQL. I have also pasted the create table string.
If someone knows the answer please help. Thanks

```
final String CREATE_ITEMS_TABLE = "create table "
                   + ITEMS_TABLE + " ("
                   + ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
                   + PHOTO + " BLOB, " 
                   + TITLE + " text not null unique, "
                   + PRICE + " integer );
```

Comment: You should be getting error "Missing Right Parenthesis" for above code, because you are missing to close the ")"

Comment: In MySQL, case does not matter, but you are not using MySQL. In SQLite, [data types do no matter](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). Show the error.